# Selenium Testcase failed, element id not found

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE 2.9.0 and tried to run a test case which logs in on a mail account and sends an email. Now, the test-case fails and it says as below:-

```
"Element id=Passwd not found"
```

I have tried running the tc in slow mode, using `clickAndWait` instead of `click` and changed the target multiple times, and it always fails on the password id. But the command before the one in question is executed perfectly fine, and there only the target is different (email instead of password)

Thanks in advance,

Sarah

Comment: Can you post the html or link you are targeting.

Comment: well, the problem with the login is solved now, but now it fails on clicking the div for creating a new mail. Do you know what that could be?

Comment: Without you providing a relevant HTML snippet of the page you're testing, right now it would be a total guess as to why it's not working. Typically it could be a mistake in the xpath/css-selector.

Comment: You are using selenium IDE which is ideally a record-play tool. Is it recording your above steps? If yes , then you can easily  get the exact selector and its target through source. If No, do provide html source, so that people can help you out better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

try with the waitforelementpresent, or use fluwentwait

```
selenium.waitForElementPresent(“myFooElement”);
selenium.click(“myFooElement”);
```